# event.key seems to not be Key [pynput]

Tags: python, pynput

I am writing an application which uses pynput to gather raw keyboard input. I needed a form of key event that could be instantiated, deleted, enabled, and disabled arbitrarily during runtime, so pynput's Global Hotkey system wouldn't work. So, I created my own event class:

```py
keyEvents = []

class keyEvent():
    def __init__(self, key, callback, onPress, onRelease):
        self.key = key,
        self.callback = callback
        self.onPress = onPress
        self.onRelease = onRelease
        self.active = True
        self.calls = []
        keyEvents.append(self)

    # Called from listener thread, do not call callbacks from listener thread because then things happen at unpredictable times
    def fire(self, state):
        if self.active:
            print('{} fired {}({})'.format(self.key, self.callback, state))
            if self.onPress and state: self.calls.append(True)
            elif self.onRelease and not state: self.calls.append(False)

def _onKeyPress(key):
    print(key, key == keyboard.Key.enter)
    for event in keyEvents:
        if event.key == key: event.fire(True)
        else: print('Event did not fire {} != {}'.format(event.key, key))

def _onKeyRelease(key):
    for event in keyEvents:
        if event.key == key: event.fire(False)
```

And here I create several events, which are polled by `menu.exec`:

```py
class menu():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.items = []
        self.keyEvents = [
            keyEvent(keyboard.Key.left,  self._keyLeft,  True, False),
            keyEvent(keyboard.Key.right, self._keyRight, True, False),
            keyEvent(keyboard.Key.up,    self._keyUp,    True, False),
            keyEvent(keyboard.Key.down,  self._keyDown,  True, False),
            keyEvent(keyboard.Key.enter, self._keyEnter, True, False)
        ]
        for event in self.keyEvents: event.active = False

    ...

    def exec(self):
        for event in self.keyEvents: event.active = True
        self.refresh()
        self.active = True
        while self.active:
            for event in self.keyEvents:
                for call in event.calls:
                    event.callback(call)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

When I run the app, it gives me this output after I press the enter key:

```
Key.enter True
Event did not fire (<Key.left: <65361>>,) != Key.enter
Event did not fire (<Key.right: <65363>>,) != Key.enter
Event did not fire (<Key.up: <65362>>,) != Key.enter
Event did not fire (<Key.down: <65364>>,) != Key.enter
Event did not fire (<Key.enter: <65293>>,) != Key.enter
```

The first line tells me that the key passed to `_onKeyPress` is indeed `keyboard.Key.enter`. The last 5 lines tell me that `_onKeyPress` refused to call `event.fire` for all 5 events, including the one that was assigned to `keyboard.Key.enter`. Nowhere else in the code does `event.key` get modified. It is first set in `keyEvent.__init__` and accessed in `_onKeyPressed` for the comparison and yet, the enter key that `_onKeyPressed` sees in the `event` object is different. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! In `keyEvent.__init__` I had this loose comma:

```py
class keyEvent():
    def __init__(self, key, callback, onPress, onRelease):
        self.key = key,
        ...
```

Loose commas are like loose wires. They get in trouble.